# Como exibir o div oculto após o recarregamento da página?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

Olá, pessoal.

Estou desenvolvendo uma página onde há um botão oculto que aparece após um certo tempo.

Meu código:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<div class="diminuir-video" style="padding:30.25% 0 0 0;position:relative; 
max-width: 800px;">




<iframe src="LINK_DO_VIDEO" 
style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" autoplay 
width="840" height="550" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen 
mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="show--div-20sec">
    <p><a href="https://google.com.br" target="_blank" 
class="btn-01">TESTE</a>
   </p>
</div>


</div>
  <script 
src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'> 
 </script>



    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

No JS eu tenho a função para que o div seja exibido após 18:40:

```
$(function() {
var iframe = $('#video')[0];
  console.log()
var player = $f(iframe);

// When the player is ready, add listeners for pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {    
    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
    player.addEvent('playProgress', onPlayProgress);
});

// Call the API when a button is pressed
$('button').bind('click', function() {
    player.api($(this).text().toLowerCase());
});

function onPause() {
}

function onFinish() {
}
var time;
if (localStorage.getItem('cache') === 'true') {
  time = 0;
} else {
  time = 1120;
  localStorage.setItem('cache', 'true');
}
function onPlayProgress(data) {
  if (data.seconds >= time) {
    $('.show--div-20sec').css('display', 'block')
  }
}
});
```

O que eu precisaria agora é que, quando o usuário recarregue a página, ao invés de esperar 18:40 para reaparecer o botão, ele seja exibido de imediato.

Obrigado!

Comment: Reescreva a sua pergunta, da forma como esta ela fica muito ampla.

Comment: Você já começou alguma coisa? se sim, edita a pergunta e coloca até onde você chegou. abs

Comment: @BrunoAngeoletto acabei de editar a pergunta, muito obrigado pelo feed back!

Comment: Você pode usar [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage#Examples) e armazenar a informação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize tente utilizar esse...

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show-div-20sec" style="display: none;">
<p><a href="https://google.com.br" target="_blank"
      class="btn-01">TESTE</a>
</p>
</div>
<script>
if (localStorage.getItem('cache3') === 'true') {
    $('.show-div-20sec').css('display','')
} else {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.show-div-20sec').css('display','')
    }, 20000);
    localStorage.setItem('cache3', 'true')
}
</script>
```

Comment: Zero, eu acabei de tentar colocar esse parâmetro que vc me informou, mas não funcionou. Editei minha pergunta com o JS completo, pode verificar se inseri da maneira correta?

Comment: Quer que ele apareça depois de 20000 segundos?

Comment: Zero, sua resposta me ajudou. Deu tudo certo.

Comment: Outra dúvida, ao inves do cache, como poderia considerar os cookies da página?

Comment: Com cookie é um pouco mais complicado, ele serve para manter conexão com o cliente, no caso entre servidor e cliente. No seu caso é melhor utilizar o cache. Mas para utilizar cookie no javascript é fácil, `document.cookie = {seu cookie}`, você pode gravar seu pelo formato de GET, padrão de envio por URL {http://www.meusite.com.br/index.php?categoria=3&pag=2&tipo=5} 
Veja: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: Exemplo: `document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";`

Comment: Mas para você precisará ler o seu cookie no memento em que o usuário entrar no seu site. Então terá uma função para ler e entender ele.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda, Zero. Na minha maquina local funcionou a validação do cache, quando subo para o domínio ele não cria cache algum. Irei verificar sobre isso.